# You're a disgrace!

Tags: idiomatic-language

> You're a disgrace!

1. Is the statement natural without adding "to... (something)" after it?
2. How strong a statement is it?

Comment: Yes, the sentence is perfectly fine as is. It's very strong.

Comment: Though it could be said semi-humorously, for example to a naughty child.

Comment: If it is left unstated, then "... to me" or perhaps "... to everyone" would be implied.

Comment: Yes, it's fine but would only be used by older-ish people.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is natural in that way. For example: The UK (**It**) rail system **is** **a** national **disgrace**. -The sentence didn't need a complement with "to". I can say it has a very negative meaning because you express being ashamed of somebody.

Comment: It's not that bad - Crossrail is a pretty good engineering achievement, and the rolling stock fleet is getting a big update these days.